# listing out all the datastores in specific esx host from Pysphere

Tags: python-2.7

I want to get all the datastores from a specific cluster. I will be using this for my vapp deployment.

i tried the following snippet:

```
clusters = server.get_clusters()
for c_mor, c_name in clusters.items():
    for ds_mor, name in server.get_datastores(from_mor=c_mor).items():
        props = VIProperty(server, ds_mor)
        print props.name
```

However, this does not give me the list. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It's to late for answer this question. this my code.

```
from pysphere import VIServer, VIProperty 

server = VIServer() 
server.connect(server, username, password) 

for ds_mor, name in server.get_hosts().items(): 
    props = VIProperty(server, ds_mor) 
    for item in props.datastore :
        print item.info.name

server.disconnect()
```

Comment: For who-ever flagged this for the VLQ queue: I see no reason to delete this answer. If this answer is wrong or misleading you can downvote and point out the flaws in the comments.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow! Your solution looks really interesting... I'm not that familiar with python myself, so I can't tell how well it answers the question. It's often a good idea to provide a bit of explanation about your solution and how it solves the original problem. that way total newbies on the site (or newbies to python like me) can learn from you and how you have solved this problem. Don't forget that what may be obvious and simple to you, is likely not so obvious to a complete beginner! If you can edit your answer to add a bit more explanation, I'd be grateful :)

Comment: @JonasLibbrecht see the answer below. That way you won't iterate through hosts.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but if anyone outside is looking for a solution (this is the first result in google), this will directly gather information from datastores:

```python
from pysphere import VIServer, VIProperty
import ssl

default_context = ssl._create_default_https_context
server = VIServer()
#user = the-user-to-connect-to-vsphere
#password = the-password-from-the-user
#host = the-vsphere-hostname-or-ip
try:
    ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
    server.connect(host, user, password)
    for ds_mor, name in server.get_datastores().items():
        props = VIProperty(server, ds_mor)
        print "Datastore name: ", name
    server.disconnect()

finally:
    ssl._create_default_https_context = default_context
```

This will connect to self-signed VSphere, as is usual de case in an intranet.